# Getting ID of product from nopcommerce IConsumer<EntityFinalised<Product> Event

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nopcommerce

Ok so im getting an error message about an invalid Id Column:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while
>   updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Id'. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand
>   t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2
>   identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.b__2(UpdateTranslator
>   ut) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T
>   noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions
>   options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__27()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions
>   options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions
>   options) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() at
>   Nop.Data.EfRepository`1.Insert(T entity) in
>   C:\projects\snowys-website\Libraries\Nop.Data\EfRepository.cs:line 81
>   at
>   Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Enhancements.Services.AmazonProductService.InsertAmazonProduct(AmazonProduct
>   amazonProduct) at
>   Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Enhancements.Events.ProductSaveConsumer.HandleEvent(EntityFinalised`1
>   eventMessage) at
>   Nop.Services.Events.EventPublisher.PublishToConsumer[T](IConsumer`1 x,
>   T eventMessage) in
>   C:\projects\snowys-website\Libraries\Nop.Services\Events\EventPublisher.cs:line
>   40

This is my product save event class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Nop.Core;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog;
using Nop.Core.Events;
using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
using Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Enhancements.Domain;
using Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Enhancements.Services;
using Nop.Services.Events;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Events;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Enhancements.Events
{
/// <summary>
/// This class is used to detect when a Product has been edited so we can update the relevant Amazon fields.
/// </summary>
public class ProductSaveConsumer : IConsumer<EntityFinalised<Product>>
{
    public void HandleEvent(EntityFinalised<Product> eventMessage)
    {
        // This event is triggered multiple times when a product is updated.
        // We only want to update the amazon fields once, as to avoid
        // performance issues.
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        if (httpContext != null && httpContext.Request.Form.HasKeys() &&
            httpContext.Request.Form.Get("AmazonProductSKU") != null)
        {
            #region Fields

            // Register services we will need to update the database fields
            var _amazonProductService = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IAmazonProductService>();

            // Other variables
            var form = httpContext.Request.Form;
            var isNewAmazonProduct = true;

            #endregion

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("form has been submitted");

            // Get the AmazonProduct row from our custom table for the product (if it already exists)
            // isNewAmazonProduct = false;
            var amazonProductExists = false;//_amazonProductService.GetAmazonProductById(eventMessage.Entity.Id).Exists(x => x.ProductId == eventMessage.Entity.Id);

            if (amazonProductExists) {
                isNewAmazonProduct = false;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("not new amazon product");
            }
            else
            {
                isNewAmazonProduct = true;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("is new amazon product");
            }

            var amazonProduct = new AmazonProduct();

            //set the product id
            amazonProduct.ProductID = Int32.Parse(eventMessage.Entity.Id.ToString());

            // Now let's update the fields
            // AmazonProductSKU
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductSKU"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonProductSKU = form["AmazonProductSKU"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product sku");
            }

            // AmazonID
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonID"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonID = form["AmazonID"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon id");
            }

            // AmazonProductIDType
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductIDType"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonID = form["AmazonProductIDType"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product id type");
            }

            // AmazonProductTitle
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductTitle"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonProductTitle = form["AmazonProductTitle"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product title");
            }

            // AmazonProductDescription
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductDescription"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonProductDescription = form["AmazonProductDescription"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product description");
            }

            // AmazonProductManufacturer
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductManufacturer"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonProductManufacturer = form["AmazonProductManufacturer"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product manufacturer");
            }

            // AmazonProductType
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductType"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonProductType = form["AmazonProductType"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product type");
            }

            // AmazonProductBrandName
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductBrandName"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonProductBrandName = form["AmazonProductBrandName"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product brand name");
            }

            // AmazonProductShippingTemplate
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductShippingTemplate"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonProductShippingTemplate = form["AmazonProductShippingTemplate"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product shipping template");
            }

            // AmazonProductSeoRecommendedBrowserNodes1
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductSeoRecommendedBrowserNodes1"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonProductSeoRecommendedBrowserNodes1 = form["AmazonProductSeoRecommendedBrowserNodes1"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product seo node 1");
            }

            // AmazonProductSeoRecommendedBrowserNodes2
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductSeoRecommendedBrowserNodes2"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonProductSeoRecommendedBrowserNodes2 = form["AmazonProductSeoRecommendedBrowserNodes2"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product seo node 2");
            }

            // AmazonProductMainImgUrl
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductMainImgUrl"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonProductMainImgUrl = form["AmazonProductMainImgUrl"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product main image url");
            }

            // AmazonProductCountryOfPublication
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductCountryOfPublication"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonProductCountryOfPublication = form["AmazonProductCountryOfPublication"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product country of pub");
            }

            // AmazonProductMfgWarrantySwitchedOffAu
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductMfgWarrantySwitchedOffAu"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonProductMfgWarrantySwitchedOffAu = form["AmazonProductMfgWarrantySwitchedOffAu"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product mfg warranty");
            }

            // AmazonKeyProductFeatures1
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonKeyProductFeatures1"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonKeyProductFeatures1 = form["AmazonKeyProductFeatures1"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product feature 1");
            }

            // AmazonKeyProductFeatures2
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonKeyProductFeatures2"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonKeyProductFeatures2 = form["AmazonKeyProductFeatures2"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product feature 2");
            }

            // AmazonKeyProductFeatures3
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonKeyProductFeatures3"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonKeyProductFeatures3 = form["AmazonKeyProductFeatures3"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product feature 3");
            }

            // AmazonKeyProductFeatures4
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonKeyProductFeatures4"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonKeyProductFeatures4 = form["AmazonKeyProductFeatures4"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product feature 4");
            }

            // AmazonKeyProductFeatures5
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonKeyProductFeatures5"]))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonKeyProductFeatures5 = form["AmazonKeyProductFeatures5"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product feature 5");
            }

            // AmazonProductPrice
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["AmazonProductPrice"].ToString()))
            {
                amazonProduct.AmazonProductPrice = Decimal.Parse(form["AmazonProductPrice"]);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product price");
            }

            // Call the update or insert function (depending on whether or not the AmazonProduct already existed)
            if (isNewAmazonProduct)
            {
                _amazonProductService.InsertAmazonProduct(amazonProduct);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product inserted");
            }
            else {
                _amazonProductService.UpdateAmazonProduct(amazonProduct);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("amazon product updated");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Anyone know why the error is caused, am I not accessing the product Id right?

Cheers

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: I have added answer, problem was not from what I thought

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out it was a problem with how my `amazonproduct.cs` domain and `amazonproductmap.cs` were setup. Not the way I was accessing the product id.

In my `amazonproduct.cs` file I was inheriting the `baseentity`:

```
using Nop.Core;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Enhancements.Domain
{
    public class AmazonProduct : BaseEntity //I was inheriting the baseentity
    {
        //code omitted
    }
}
```

So because I was inheriting the base entity, it was using a field Id which was causing the problem.

So in my `amazonproductmap` I had to ignore this column:

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Enhancements.Domain;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Enhancements.Data
{
public class AmazonProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AmazonProduct>
{
    public AmazonProductMap()
    {
        ToTable("amazonProductInfo");
        HasKey(p => p.AmazonProductID);

        Ignore(p => p.Id); //I had to ignore this column
        //other fields omitted
    }
}
}
```

I hope this helps someone else :)